# Multiple like buttons showing same count on a page, iFrame issue?

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, facebook-like

I have a web page here [StoneWire News](http://www.stonewire.net/News.php) which is a news page driven by MYSQL.  It shows several news articles on the page, each a different row in the DataBase.  Each news item has a like link associated with it using the code below.  This has worked for a while but now everything has gone screwy and as you can see, the like's seems to have all become associated with one another.  From reading around I can see iframes may be the cause of the problem here.  Any ideas what I should do to fix it?

Thanks

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.StoneWire.net%2FNews.php%3FnewsId%3D<?php echo $row_rsNews['newsId']; ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is showing results for the entire website because of the iFrame, I believe. There are no separate pages to "like" - even though your posts are brought in through your DB. I believe you should probably test for two separate pages and try that, and make sure that a user can click a heading to open that page in a separate window. Facebook may like that.
Try putting a like button on Gigs.php and also News.php and see if they stay "separated."

Comment: so does that mean it cant detect pages or any unique ID as different links?